# I'm not able to toggle my switch in the simulator when I add my switch programmatically

Tags: swift

The switch stays off even when I tap on it. Why is that?

```
  let testSwitch = UISwitch()
  self.view.addSubview(testSwitch)
```

[image]

Comment: Check `.isEnabled` == true?  Check in the view debugger you haven't accidentally put another view over the top?

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my system.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc func mySwitchAction() {
     print("testSwitch button hit.")
   }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testSwitch = UISwitch()
        testSwitch.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 240, width: 100, height: 40)
        testSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mySwitchAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(testSwitch)
    }
}
```